# DAX Query to Get Distinct Items from Multiple Tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

### Problem

I'm trying to generate a table of distinct email addresses from multiple source tables. However, with the `UNION` statement on the outer part of the statement, it isn't generating a truly distinct list.

### Code

```
Participants = UNION(DISTINCT('Registrations'[Email Address]), DISTINCT( 'EnteredTickets'[Email]))
```

*Note that while I'm starting with just two source tables, I need to expand this to 3 or 4 by the end of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A combination of using `VALUES` on the table selects plus wrapping the whole statement in one more `DISTINCT` did the trick:

```
Participants = DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES('Registrations'[Email Address]), VALUES( 'EnteredTickets'[Email])))
```

Comment: Yup that's the exact solution that I too figured out.

Comment: I got a circular dependency warning with this method. I tested the method posted below and that worked. I think the presence of VALUE, for my tables, was the issue.

Comment: Strangely, `VALUES(UNION(VALUES...` doesn't work - apparently the parameters for VALUES function differs from DISTINCT in some nuanced way

Answer (score 2):

If you want a bridge table with unique values for all different tables, use `DISTINCT` instead of `VALUES`:

```
Participants =
FILTER (
    DISTINCT (
        UNION (
            TOPN ( 0, ROW ("NiceEmail", "asdf") ), -- adds zero rows table with nice new column name
            DISTINCT ( 'Registrations'[Email Address] ),
            DISTINCT ( 'EnteredTickets'[Email] )
        )
    ),
    [NiceEmail] <> BLANK () -- removes all blank emails
)
```

`DISTINCT` AND `VALUES` may lead to different results. Essentially, using `VALUES`,  you are likely to end up with (unwanted) blank value in your list. 
Check this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/values-function-dax#related-functions

You might also like information under this link which you can use to get a specific column name for your table of distinct values:

[DAX create empty table with specific column names and no rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689581/dax-create-empty-table-with-specific-column-names-and-no-rows)