# DAX create empty table with specific column names and no rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to create a table with a specified column name and no rows at all. The following oneliner does what I want but shows error message that there should be second argument in ROW function.

```
EmptyTable = ROW ("Product")
```

I would like to use it for making bridge tables with desired column name. For example I want Product_bridge table to have a column "Product".

```
Product_bridge = DISTINCT(
    UNION(
         DISTINCT(      Sales[Prod_Name]        ) 
        ,DISTINCT( Dictionary[Prod_DifferntName])
        ,DISTINCT(  PriceList[P]                )
        ))
```

The code above gets me the name of the first table, in this case Prod_Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just filter it. Or select TOPN 0.

TOPN:

```
Table = TOPN(0;DATATABLE("Product";STRING;{{}}))
```

FILTER:

```
Table = FILTER(DATATABLE("Product";STRING;{{}});0)
```

Comment: How does this filter work? What this 0 is supposed to mean? `DATATABLE("Product";STRING;{{}})` creates a table with BLANK value in the first row. Can't we filter explicitly <>BLANK()?

Comment: Is this 0 supposed to create impossible to meet condition? Similarly to `FILTER(DATATABLE("Product", STRING,{{"Apple"}}), 1=2)` ?

Comment: Yes, just like you can use FALSE() aswell

Comment: But I do not understand your single zero filter. FILTER second argument is a check for true or false. Something like A=B or A=TRUE. How does your single zero work?

Comment: implicit conversion to boolean, False

Answer (score 2):

This is how I create empty DAX tables:

```
EmptyTable = DATATABLE (
    "Other Measures", INTEGER, 
    { 
        { 0 }
    } 
)
```

Comment: It is not empty. This table has one row with value 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to [mxix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3665707/mxix) answer a few useful oneliners for making *one-column empty table with desired name*:

```
OneLiner1 = TOPN(0, ROW("Product", "Apple"))
OneLiner2 = FILTER(ROW("Product", "Apple"), 1=2)
```

Or if you want to define column type:

```
OneLiner3 = TOPN(0, DATATABLE("Product", STRING,{{"Apple"}}) )
```

So the snipped for bridge table is:

```
Product_bridge = DISTINCT(
    UNION(
         TOPN(0, ROW("Product", "Apple"))
        ,DISTINCT(      Sales[Prod_Name]        ) 
        ,DISTINCT( Dictionary[Prod_DifferntName])
        ,DISTINCT(  PriceList[P]                )
        ))
```