# how to create table to hold measures in SSAS tabular cube

Tags: ssas-tabular

I want to create an empty table in a SSAS tabular cube (in SSDT, in Visual Studio) to hold all of my cube's measures.  In Power BI Desktop, I would do so by creating a 1-column "empty" table in Power Query, loading it into the model, put 1 measure on it, go back into Power Query, delete the empty column, re-load the model, and continue putting measures on the table.  But, I don't see an option to do this in SSDT (in Visual Studio) without using a calculated table.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Picking up (and perhaps simplifying) TheRizza's excellent idea - for which thanks - I used this:

[image]

You can obviously (I presume) create as many columns as you like.  I tried putting a measure in the second column, then removing this from the table calculation formula, and SSAS moves the measure back into the first column (so you don't lose it).

Comment: A recent find for me is that text columns are expensive and number columns are cheap. For every text column, SSAS creates 1M of overhead, but a number column only takes 544 bytes (can see from DAX Studio in VertiPaq Analyzer). It's not a huge problem for a few columns, but it stacks up the more columns and DAX tables that you have. I would substitute 0 for "" in your formula.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that. If the table has no columns, you won't be able to see the measures in Visual Studio:
[image: Error message]

I would create a one column table using the DAX formula `={0}` and hide the column in the model and not worry about it.

[image]
**Edit:** *Disregard `={""}` in picture and use `={0}` instead. Numbers are stored significantly more efficiently than text, and you will reduce the size of your model using `={0}`, especially if you have a lot of DAX tables.*

If you want to name the column and have no rows, you can use this [more obscure formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689581/dax-create-empty-table-with-specific-column-names-and-no-rows):

```
=TOPN(0, ROW("Column", 0))
```